# Debounce an Observable based on the output of another observable

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm looking for the right operator and an elegent way to debounce a observable based on the output timing of another.

Basic problem:

'If during the past 3 seconds observable A has emitted, debounce the emit of Observable B until these three seconds have passed'

Additonally, this is applied in the context of NGRX actions/effects, rephrasing the basic problem in this context yields:

'Debounce an effect based on the recent history of another effect or action'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are after:

```js
const since = Date.now();

const actionA = new Rx.Subject();
const actionB = new Rx.Subject();

const debouncedB = Rx.Observable
  .combineLatest(
    actionA.switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.concat(
      Rx.Observable.of(true),
      Rx.Observable.of(false).delay(3000)
    ))
    .startWith(false),
    actionB
  )
  .filter(([debouncing]) => !debouncing)
  .map(([, b]) => b)
  .distinctUntilChanged();

debouncedB.subscribe(
  (value) => console.log(value, `T+${((Date.now() - since) / 1000).toFixed(0)}`)
);

actionB.next("b1");
actionA.next("a1");
actionB.next("b2");
actionB.next("b3");
actionB.next("b4");

setTimeout(() => actionB.next("b5"), 4000);
setTimeout(() => actionA.next("a2"), 5000);
setTimeout(() => actionB.next("b6"), 6000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

It converts each A action into a debouncing signal that's either `true` or `false`. When `true`, B actions will be debounced until the signal becomes `false`.

`switchMap` is used so that if another A action is received whilst the signal is `true`, the signal wont be set to `false` until a three seconds after the latest A action.

Comment: Actually, there is an edge case. It won't emit anything until at least one A action is emitted. That might or might be a problem, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Fixed it. It won't matter if the A action isn't emitted, now.

Comment: A useful extension would be to apply this to the case of ngrx effects, but the current answer is more than enough in my eyes.

Comment: In an `ngrx` context, all you need to do is replace `actionA` with `this.actions.ofType("A")`, etc. - where `actions` is the `ngrx` `Actions` observable that you inject into an effects class.

Comment: FYI, I was adding something similar to this to a library of useful observable stuff and noticed that it needs `distinctUntilChanged` on the end - otherwise, a stale B action will emitted if none is received whilst debouncing.